# useState and splice react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a big problem with useState in react..
I just want to remove an object from an array using slice and setState this array using hooks.
But it's not working I don't know why ..

Look:

```
  const [ img, setImg ] = useState(allImages);

  const removeImageAtIndex = (index) => {
    img.splice(index, 1); // when i console.log i can see that the object has been removed
    setImg(img);         // nothing changes
    /* FOR TEST
    setImg([]); // if I remove all img, it's working 
    */
    /* I already tried this:
    let temp = img;
    img.splice(index, 1);
    setImg(temp);
    */
  /* SOLUTION
    setImg([...img]);
  */
  };

  return (
    <div>
      { variants.map((variant, index) => {
        return <img key={index } onClick={ () => removeImageAtIndex(index)} src={img.src} />
      })}
    </div>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Could you be interested in `setImg([...img])`, making a shallow copy of your array from which you removed the item already?

Comment: Oh yeah it's working, can you explain me why ??

Comment: because setImg now gets a different reference, it's a copy of your array (in fact `setImg( img.slice() )` would have worked as well, just verify the duplicate

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're mutating the state directly, that's why it doesn't work. Use immutable array methods together with the functional form of `setState` to remove items from array, for ex with `filter`:

```
setImg(currentImg => currentImg.filter((img, i) => i !== index));
```

Comment: filter and splice are not the same.

Comment: filter is the best practice for remove index. For me its working fine. Thanks